# Moving the “share” button

Tags: plugin-development

I am using YITH Share for Discount Plugin.
I want to ask how can I move the “share” button upper?
Here is my website link:
http://www.crystalyard.com/product/%E7%B2%89%E6%99%B6%E6%89%8B%E9%8F%88/
The “share” button is right below the “Add To Cart” button.
If I have to edit the plugin file, which file should I edit? What code should I use?

Comment: Thank you for your post, but third-party plugins and themes are off-topic here on WPSE. Our community is focused on WordPress core functionality. Please try reaching out to the developers of the YITH Share plugin for advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this with css as well, to add button before add to cart, add the following css code in your theme style file i.e : style.css

```
.ywsfd-social {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12%;
    left: 40px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}
```

it will work ok till 1024 screen, you have to add media query to perfectly fit it in smaller screens.